# Configure HealthChecksUI for AspNetCore WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, health-check

I  am setting up the HealthCheckUI for the ASPNETCore web api (.Net Core 3.1). However `http://localhost:1234/healthchecks-ui` keeps calling the default api `http://localhost:1234/healthchecks-api` instead of `http://localhost:1234/health` as configured.

The `/health` returns JSON data as expected and `/healthchecks-api` returns `[]`.

[image]

Any idea please?

Setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
   ...
   services.AddHealthChecksUI(setupSettings: setup=> 
            {
                setup.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(15); //time in seconds between check
                setup.MaximumHistoryEntriesPerEndpoint(60); //maximum history of checks
                setup.SetApiMaxActiveRequests(1); //api requests concurrency

                setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("api", "/health"); //map health check api
            })
            .AddInMemoryStorage();
}
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
   ...
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions { ResponseWriter = HealthCheckResponseWriter.WriteAsync });
                endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();

            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My HealthCheck JSON is not good format. Working fine with the default `UIResponseWriter`:

```
endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions { ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse });
```